# List<int> to IEnumerable<IComparable>

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, icomparable

I can implicitly cast an int to a IComparable. I can also cast a List or an array to a IEnumerable.

But why can't I implicitly cast a List to a IEnumerable?

I tested this with the .net framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

Code to test:

```
IComparable test1;
int t1 = 5;
test1 = t1; //OK

IEnumerable<int> test2;
List<int> t2 = new List<int>();
int[] t3 = new int[] { 5, 6 };
test2 = t2; //OK
test2 = t3; //OK

TabAlignment[] test;

IEnumerable<IComparable> test3;
test3 = t2; //error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IComparable>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generic variance doesn't apply to value types, basically. So while you *can*

You'd need to box each value:

```
IEnumerable<IComparable> test3 = t2.Cast<IComparable>();
```

So while this is valid because `string` is a reference type:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<IComparable> comparables = strings;
```

... the equivalent doesn't work for `List<int>`, and you need to box as you go.

Comment: Having read through your answer and compared with mine (and then tested in code), I realise mine is wrong in this instance as it deals with conversions from List -> List rather than List -> IEnumerable, but I'm puzzled why that makes a difference. Can you explain?

Comment: @JonEgerton: I suspect you put generic type arguments in that comment, but I can't see them. Try again, with backticks around the code-related bits.

Comment: @JonEgerton: Okay, reading through your answer, then your comment again... - it's because `List<T>` isn't covariant in `T`, but `IEnuemrable<T>` is (as of .NET 4). Classes can never be variant. Search for "generic variance" on MSDN for more details :)

Comment: I think I get it, but I'll follow it up - thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

It a common confusion with lists of generics, but basically if you generalise it it makes more sense:

Consider this setup:

```
public interface IA{
}

public class A : IA{
}

var listA = new List<A>();
```

The following line wouldn't work:

```
List<IA> listI = ListA;
```

Essentially this is because, even though `A : IA`, `List<I> does not : List<A>` - they're completely separate types.

You can do the cast easily enough though using the `Cast` method:

```
listI = ListA.Cast<IA>();
```

So in your case you could do

```
test3 = t2.Cast<IComparable>();
```